# Reading random struct array element from binary file

Tags: c, arrays, file, struct

I have an very big array (100k) in which elements are randomly placed with array index as primary key. I am trying to figure out a way to access array elements with fseek using index key as offset. For some reason no matter what offset i give, I get null back. Following is the simple representation of the problem.

Help appreciated. Sorry if this is a repost. I could not find similar question asked anywhere.

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

 typedef struct student
 {
   char *name;
   int marks;
 }student;

 student class[] = {
   [5]{"Jack",34},
   [12]{"Jane",56},
   [53]{"Joe",72}
 };

 main()
 {
   FILE *f, *f1;
   student rec;

   f = fopen("student.data", "wb");
   fwrite(class, sizeof(student), sizeof(class), f);
   fclose(f);

   if((f1 = fopen("student.data","rb"))==NULL)
   {
     printf("\nError in Opening File\n");
     exit(0);
   }

   /* I want to  seek to 12th element in the array and print 'Jane' */
   fseek(f1, sizeof(student) * 12, SEEK_SET);
   fread(&rec, sizeof(student), 1, f1);

   printf("Name:%s\n", rec.name);

   fclose(f1);
 }
```

Comment: Your struct does not contain the actual names, but just pointers to them, so they aren't getting written out to the file.

Comment: Thank you for lightning reply. Changing `char *name;` to `char name[30];` is now printing binary chars.

Comment: still bad : `fwrite(class, sizeof(student), sizeof(class), f);` : fwrite(object address, record size, number of record, file pointer)

Answer (score 0):

Your example works for me. The only thing I had to change was to use double quotes instead of single quotes for the class array initialization:

```
cat student.c; gcc student.c; ./a.out
```

gives the following output:

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

 typedef struct student
 {
   char *name;
   int marks;
 }student;

 student class[] = {
   [5]{"Jack",34},
   [12]{"Jane",56},
   [53]{"Joe",72}
 };

 main()
 {
   FILE *f, *f1;
   student rec;

   f = fopen("student.data", "wb");
   fwrite(class, sizeof(student), sizeof(class), f);
   fclose(f);

   if((f1 = fopen("student.data","rb"))==NULL)
   {
     printf("\nError in Opening File\n");
     exit(0);
   }

   /* I want to  seek to 12th element in the array and print 'Jane' */
   fseek(f1, sizeof(student) * 12, SEEK_SET);
   fread(&rec, sizeof(student), 1, f1);

   printf("Name:%s\n", rec.name);

   fclose(f1);
 }
Name:Jane
```

Comment: Hummm .... no luck here. I am still seeing null even after single quote replacement. I know what my problem is ... student.data file is getting created but nothing is getting written in it.

Comment: This cannot work correctly. The name strings are never stored to the file because the struct contains pointers. The only way this works is if it's all written and read in one program so that the name strings just happen to live at the same addresses that were written and reread.

Comment: Yes, Emmet. I did a quick compile and run test with the example. After removing the compiler warnings I saw the expected output. But of course the student struct should not hold pointers to the strings. The file is not written correctly: "cat student.data" prints
"�"�8
�H%